# Removing an entry from a GWT JSONObject

Tags: json, gwt

Let's say I have a JSONObject in GWT that looks like this: `{"name1":value1, "name2":value2}`. Is there a way to remove the `"name2":value2` key/value pair and change this object to `{"name1":value1}`? I have not found any methods that help with this approach in the [GWT Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.html).

I know there are workarounds to this, of course. Since my JSONObject is small, I am currently making a new one and putting in it all the key/value pairs other than the one I want to remove. But this won't work when I plan to pass in the JSONObject to a child function; since only the JSONObject's reference is passed in Java, I need a mutator function to actively change what the method parameter's JSONObject points to. In the worse case, I could convert the JSONObject to a String and regexp out what I don't want. But this seems prone to error and ugly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `put()`ing a `null` (as opposed to a `JSONNull`) value will [delete](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.java#248) the value for the given key.